# React doesn't have two way binding then why user changes will not make changes to `value` property for the uncontrolled input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React doesn't have two way binding then why react need to maintain its given value even if user make changes to input value

***Please explain the reason of this behaviour and how it is done?***

```
 render() {
   return <input type="text" name="fullname" value="Johnny Papa" />
 }
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to use `state`?

Comment: you may consider adding more detail to your question as your question is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the `input` is practically read only because you set the `value`. So every time react renders that input `Johnny Papa` overrides the DOM value and user can't change it. Read the documentation about [Default Values](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values).

If you want to allow edits you need to use `defaultValue`:

```
render() {
  return <input type="text" name="fullname" defaultValue="Johnny Papa" />
}
```

In this case, react sets the initial value of the `input` once and then bails out.

Comment: but when I change the dom input value using user interaction there is no setState then how come react will reset the value

Comment: Are you asking about `defaultValue` or `value`?